# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsql.jdbcDriver'

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, jndi

I am not to sure why I am unable to connect to my database. I am using JNDI, and maven to help handle the dependencies. In my context.xml in my server folder in eclipse looks like:

```
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:  
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsql.jdbcDriver'
```

context.xml

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded. -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Resource name="jdbc/Spring_Tutorial" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        username="root" driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Spring_Tutorial" />

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!-- <Manager pathname="" /> -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events 
        on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" 
        /> -->
</Context>
```

this class handles the error if it is unable to connect:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DatabaseErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
    public String handleDatabaseException(DataAccessException ex) {

        System.out.println("Error connecting to Database: "+ex);

        return "error";
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.spring.practice</groupId>
  <artifactId>offers</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<description>Database</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/Spring_Tutorial</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

I added the hsqldb jar file but I really did not think I needed it

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

From my understand I just need the mysql-connector-java dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.35</version>
</dependency>
```

My database's name is Spring_Tutorial and I am using mySQL Workbench.

Am I blindly missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a MySQL URL with a HSQL driver:

```xml
driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Spring_Tutorial" />
```

You need to use a MySQL driver instead:

```xml
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

Comment: I knew I was blindly missing something. Cut and paste error for the JNDI site... Thanks up and running